# Run SQL script on multiple schemas with Flyway

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, flyway

I am migrating the DB using Flyway. I have a SQL script file which need to run on multiple schemas hosted on a single database.

In my SQL file if I mention `${db_schema}` as the parameter and supply with different schema names, will that work? Is there any other approaches to handle this scenario?

```
SET search_path TO ${db_schema};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use placeholders in flyway to handle more than one schema. [Here's an article](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/flyway/one-flyway-migration-script-for-diverse-database-systems) that outlines how that works.